# MATLAB: a basic pitch shift over a given time similar to a sine sweep

Tags: matlab, pitch, pitch-shifting

if I have an audio that is at 1hz, how can I wavewrite it into an audio sample that is rising in pitch till it gets to the nyquist or in my case 22050hz, in matlab...thanks to the community for any insight and information in advance.

Comment: When you say sweep out, do you mean you want to set sampling frequency for reading your file from 1Hz to 2*real sampling frequency of your signal? That would be a very very very long job.

Comment: and also, you say that "I can change fs to get different pitch values of the audio sample I am up sampling or down sampling" Does that imply you are using some kind of pitch detection algorithm, and you simply want to apply it to you signal where fs is set to change?

Comment: if I have an audio that is at 1hz, how can I wavewrite it into an audio sample that is rising in pitch till it gets to the nyquist or in my case 22050hz...is there a way to set fs to an exponential value that increases with time, similar to matlabs sine sweep code.

Comment: you can use multiple wavread to read your signal (sampled at 1Hz) and assign a higher frequency when you are doing wavread.

Comment: thanks it helped but still can't sample the final audio so it is rising in pitch, may be ramp values could help, but I need the audio to sweep through all frequencies...

Comment: Okay,
Let's simplify the problem to understand what you want better.. Let's assume that the signal has a unique frequency, what do you want to do about it? Move that frequency up?

If that's what you want to do, i'd suggest you to look at fft and zero padding

Comment: let's say we waveread our own 1hz sinewav audio sample into matlab and we are not generating it in matlab, and we want its frequency to sweep from 1hz to 22050hz...basically a simple linear pitch shift similar to a sweep...a basic pitch shift over a given time.